# testing javascript scripts that use java interfaces but during testing there is not possibility to access it

Tags: javascript, java, jestjs, mockito, graalvm

Testing javascript files that use java interfaces but during testing there is not possibility to access it, so i am looking for a test framework that will provide me possibility to test js scripts and in addition allow me to mock java interfaces that are used withing mentioned scripts.

I was looking and trying different frameworks but i could not find perfect combination for my problem.